# What determines a generator as broken or unbroken?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics, lie-algebra, symmetry-breaking

From my understanding of "generators"(e.g. below is $T^a$), one is broken if:

$$T^a \phi \not= 0 \tag{1}$$

where $\phi$ is the v.e.v. of a field.

But in an example given by a lecturer we were told that some of the generators shown below, or a linear combination of them, are unbroken. I don't see how this is possible if I never obtain a $0$ as answer when multiplying the values given by the lecturer.

So **what determines a generator as broken or unbroken?**

---

*Lecturer's example:*

Generators:

$$  T^0 =\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & \\
    0 & 0 & -i & \\
    0 & i & 0 
  \end{bmatrix} ;  \hspace{5mm} T^1=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & i & \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \\
    -i & 0 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix} ;  \hspace{5mm} T^2 =\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -i & 0 & \\
    i & 0 & 0 & \\
    0 & 0 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix} ; $$

and the v.e.v. of her choice was $\phi = \frac{u}{\sqrt 2} \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    0  
  \end{bmatrix} $

---

*My attempt:*

$$T^0 \phi =\begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    i  
  \end{bmatrix} ; \hspace{5mm} T^1 \phi =\begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    -i  
  \end{bmatrix} ; \hspace{5mm}  T^2 \phi =\begin{bmatrix}
    -i  \\
    i  \\
    0  
  \end{bmatrix}$$

<s>**If my understanding is correct, the only linear combination that leads to an unbroken generator would be $T^0+T^1$ ?**</s>

Is my understanding/approach correct? I find it strange only this combination working, or is this not how to confirm if the generators are broken/unbroken?

After the explanation given in the comments below, I understand that all the generators given below are broken. Thus, to find a linear combination , $C = c_0 T^0 + c_1 T^1  + c_2 T^2$, that leads to an unbroken generator, I must find values for $c_0, c_1, c_2$ that lead to a $C\phi = 0$.

But when attempting this, it results in the following equality:

$$\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
    -i c_2  \\
    -i c_2  \\
    - ic_1 + ic_0 
  \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    0 
  \end{bmatrix} $$

**But won't this lead to an infinite number of possibilities, as $c_2 = 0$ and $c_0 = c_1$?** What linear combination can give me a broken one?

Comment: You did mention "linear combination." What would you get from $T^0 + T^1$?

Comment: I know that from that I would simply get a sum, but I am not sure how I would linearly combine these.

I know that a linear combination would be something like:

$C = c_0 T^0 + c_1 T^1  + c_2 T^2  $ 

But then am I meant to simply create 3 constant of whatever value to make this work?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. *Why* do you find this strange? Why would you expect more/other combinations? You did not explain your problem, really.

Comment: I just was uncertain of the mathematical meaning of a broken/unbroken generator, and can't quite come to terms w/ the fact that if I follow the equation presented in the comments above,  I seem to get $c_2=0$ and $c_1=c_0$. This would allow an infinite number of possible answers.

Comment: So you found that any multiple of $T_0+T_1$ annihilates your given $\langle \phi\rangle$. Why are you unsettled? You found your unbroken direction, and any multiple of zero is zero.

Comment: I thought that for the needed linear combination, I required the linear combination of the three terms, and not just of two of the three terms. I believed that I needed to find the value of the $c_0, c_1, c_2$ that would give me the 0 matrix.

Comment: The null matrix has three null eigenvectors, not just one, as you solved for. There is one unbroken direction, not three.